# Changes made within a member function cannot be seen outside its scope

Tags: c++, c++11, xml-rpc, gtkmm

I'm using a library which requires me to derive from a class it provides and then override a function.
However, I'm facing a strange situation where changes made within the member function are:

- Temporary: they last only in the scope of the member function.
- Non-persistent: In an iteration, the changes made in previous iterations are not visible.

For example, if I have a global int variable initialized to 0 which I increment in the member function, it's value pre-increment is 0 and 1 post-increment while within the member function, but always 0 outside the function's scope. Here is an example that demonstrates the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <xmlrpc-c/base.hpp>
#include <xmlrpc-c/registry.hpp>
#include <xmlrpc-c/server_abyss.hpp>

class TestWindow : public Gtk::Window {
public:
  TestWindow();
  // Called from worker thread
  void notify(void (*callback)());
  //Dispatcher handler
  void on_notification_from_worker_thread();
  //Data
  Glib::Dispatcher m_Dispatcher;
  //Callback functions
  void (*on_notify_callback)();
};

class RpcWorker {
public:
  RpcWorker(TestWindow* nw);
  TestWindow* window;
  RpcWorker* worker;
  void start_thread ();
};

RpcWorker::RpcWorker(TestWindow* nw){
  window = nw;
}

void foo (){
  std::cout << "Foo called" << std::endl;
}

void bar (){
  std::cout << "Bar called" << std::endl;
}

class testFunction : public xmlrpc_c::method {
public:
  testFunction(TestWindow* nw, RpcWorker* worker);
  TestWindow* window;
  RpcWorker* worker;
  void execute(xmlrpc_c::paramList const& paramList,
               xmlrpc_c::value *   const  retvalP) {
    window->notify(bar);
    *retvalP = xmlrpc_c::value_int(0);
  }
};

testFunction::testFunction(TestWindow* nw, RpcWorker* wk){
  window = nw;
  worker = wk;
}

void RpcWorker::start_thread() {
  std::cout << "Thread started" << std::endl;
  xmlrpc_c::registry myRegistry;
  xmlrpc_c::methodPtr const testFunctionP(new testFunction(window, this));
  myRegistry.addMethod("next.hideMinibuffer", testFunctionP);
  xmlrpc_c::serverAbyss myAbyssServer (myRegistry, 8080, "/tmp/xmlrpc_log");
  myAbyssServer.run();
}

TestWindow::TestWindow(){
  m_Dispatcher.connect(sigc::mem_fun
                       (*this, &TestWindow::on_notification_from_worker_thread));
  on_notify_callback = foo;
}

void TestWindow::notify(void (*callback)()) {
  on_notify_callback = callback;
  m_Dispatcher.emit();
}

void TestWindow::on_notification_from_worker_thread() {
  on_notify_callback();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "Test.Window");
  TestWindow window;
  RpcWorker worker = RpcWorker(&window);
  std::thread* rpc_worker_thread = new std::thread(&RpcWorker::start_thread, &worker);
  return app->run(window);
}
```

In this example, the on_notify_callback variable in the TestWindow class is initially set to point to function foo but later changed to function bar. Calling the function through the pointer while within the execute method immediately after changing it, function bar is invoked. However, once outside the scope of method execute, on_notify_callback points to foo.
What is causing this situation, and how do I fix it or work around it?

Comment: There's too much extraneous stuff in your posted code than the core problem you describe. Please create a [mcve].

Comment: I understand that the code is rather verbose. However, the problem only occurs specifically when I'm using the xmlrpc-c library. The code I'm working with is much larger, and this is the most minimal version I could make that still demonstrates the problem. If you have some ideas about how I could make it even more minimal, please let me know and I'll do so.

Comment: Where is the variable that demonstrate the problem?

Comment: You have xml-rpc and gtkmm in your code. You could try removing one of them to find out which one is not a factor.

Comment: In this example, the variable demonstrating the problem is the on_notify_callback function pointer. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try to make an example without gtkmm as the problem lies with xml-rpc-c. I'll replace it with a simple thread instead.